# How to insert these values below in a dynamic drop down menu

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamic drop down menu which displays each value from number 1- 10:

```
$min_year = 1;
$max_year = 10;
$years = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012
$durationHTML = '';
$durationHTML .= '<select name="duration" id="durationDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$durationHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
foreach ($years as $year) {
    $durationHTML .= "<option>$year</option>".PHP_EOL;  // if no value attribute, value will be whatever is inside option tag, in this case, $year
}
$durationHTML .= '</select>';
```

What I want to do though is change the values so that it displays these values below:

```
1
1/2
2
2/3
3
3/4
4
4/5
5
5/6
6
6/7
7
7/8
8
8/9
9
9/10
10
```

My question is that how can I dynamically display these values above?

**UPDATE:**

```
$min_year = 1;
$max_year = 10;
$years = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012
$durationHTML = '';
$durationHTML .= '<select name="duration" id="durationDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$durationHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($years); $i++)
{
  $current_year = $years[$i];
  $durationHTML .= "<option>{$current_year}</option";
  if($i != (sizeof($years) - 1 )) //So you don't try to grab 11 because it doesn't exist.
  {
    $next_year = $years[$i+1];
    $durationHTML .= "<option>{$current_year}/{$next_year}</option>";
  }
}

$durationHTML .= '</select>';
```

Below is what it outputs:

```
11/2
22/3
33/4
44/5
55/6
66/7
77/8
88/9
99/10
10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you;

```
$min_year = 1;
$max_year = 10;
$years = range($min_year, $max_year); // returns array with numeric values of 1900 - 2012
$durationHTML = '';
$durationHTML .= '<select name="duration" id="durationDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$durationHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
foreach ($years as $year) {
    $durationHTML .= "<option>$year</option>".PHP_EOL;  
    if ($year != $max_year) {
         $nextYear = $year + 1;
         $durationHTML .= "<option>$year / $nextYear</option>".PHP_EOL;              
    }
}
$durationHTML .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways you could do this.

The easiest would be to change your foreach loop to a simple for loop, and grab the next value and use that to form your fraction. I did this so it would be easier to read, but you don't need to store the current_year and next_year in variables, you could just echo them directly from the array.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($years); $i++)
{
  $current_year = $years[$i];
  echo "<option>{$current_year}</option";
  if($i != (sizeof($years) - 1 )) //So you don't try to grab 11 because it doesn't exist.
  {
    $next_year = $years[$i+1];
    echo "<option>{$current_year}/{$next_year}</option>";
  }
}
```